# Should I create a separate BLoC to handle the dialog in my Flutter BLoc app?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm new to flutter_bloc and i'm trying to create an app where a user can add and interact with their products i want to use a dialog for a user to add  product but i notice that when a use use that addProductState, i will nolonger be able to view the products on the products page. Should i create a sperate bloc to handle the dialog or can i use the same bloc.
My products Bloc is

```
class ProductsBloc extends Bloc<ProductsEvent, ProductsState> {
  final ProductsRepository productsRepository;
  ProductsBloc({required this.productsRepository}) : super(ProductsLoading()) {
    on<LoadProducts>(_loadProducts);
    on<AddProductEvent>(_addProduct);
    on<UpdateProduct>(_updateProduct);
    on<DeleteProduct>(_deleteProduct);
  }

  _loadProducts(event, emit) async {
    try {
      emit(ProductsLoading());
      List<ProductModel> products = await productsRepository.getProducts();
      if (products.isEmpty) {
        emit(const ProductsLoadingError('no products found'));
      } else {
        emit(ProductsLoaded(products));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      emit(ProductsLoadingError(e.toString()));
    }
  }

  _addProduct(AddProductEvent event, emit) async {
    try {
      emit(ProductsLoading());
      ProductModel np = await productsRepository.addProduct(event.product);
      // emit(NewProductAdded(event.product));
      print(np.name);
      emit(NewProductAdded(np));
    } catch (e) {
      emit(NewProductError(e.toString()));
    }
  }

  _updateProduct(event, emit) async {
    try {
      emit(ProductsLoading());
      await productsRepository.addProduct(event.product);
      emit(ProductUpdated(event.product));
    } catch (e) {
      emit(UpdateProductError(e.toString()));
    }
  }

  _deleteProduct(event, emit) async {}
}
```

and my products page is as follows:

```
class Products extends StatelessWidget {
  const Products({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          foregroundColor: Colors.black,
          centerTitle: true,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(
              BootstrapIcons.arrow_left,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(
                BootstrapIcons.search,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              onPressed: () => null, // Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            ),
          ],
          title: Text(
            'Produsct & Services',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 18.sp,
              fontFamily: GoogleFonts.openSans().fontFamily,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: Container(
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: ShapeDecoration(
            color: const Color(0xFFD5DEE9),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
          ),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              showAddProductDialog(context);
            },
            child: Icon(
              BootstrapIcons.plus,
              color: AppColors.primary,
              size: 30.h,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: BlocBuilder<ProductsBloc, ProductsState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is ProductsLoading) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularLoadingIndicator(
                  color: AppColors.primary,
                ),
              );
            } else if (state is ProductsLoadingError) {
              return Center(
                  child: Text('Error loading products: ${state.error}'));
            } else if (state is ProductsLoaded) {
              var products = state.products;
              return ProductsScreen(products: products);
            } else {
              return Center(child: Text('Error loading products $state'));
            }
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

your help will really be appreciated.

Comment: Here is an answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67820324/when-to-create-new-bloc