In flutter BLoC, how to optimize the creation of repeated, multiple dart files?
I am working on a flutter project. I have 5 basic components where I have a list of items to display, add item screen and delete item screen. So in all of the modules I am gonna have same states & events. I want to know whether it is critical to maintain a dedicated state.dart file & event.dart file for each of the components ?
I am new to flutter BLoC and haven't implemented it yet. I do understand the implementation BLoC for a single component/module and just need a clear understanding on a broader level. Any help is appreciated.

take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67823319/13398700
